# Variable not changing on click jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have a variable I would like to change the value of on click. In console the variable changes, however it does not adjust the value inside the function. How do I change this global variable on click?

```
var maxLength = 150;

jQuery(".outer p").html(function(index, currentText) {
  if(currentText.length >= maxLength) {
    return currentText.substr(0, maxLength) + '...<div class="see-more see-more-closed"></div>';
  } else {
    return currentText
  } 
});

jQuery(".see-more").click(function() {
       var maxLength = 1000;
});

<div class="outer">
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam dictum, felis ac elementum consequat, lacus tellus cursus leo, ut imperdiet nisi lectus sed risus.
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: use `var` once time at the top of the code. Your problem is that you tried to assign a value to the local variable(use the same name with global) that why the global variable didn't change

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the variable scope by declaring it as `var` in the function. Use this instead:

```
jQuery(".see-more").click(function() {
       window.maxLength = 1000;
});
```

or simply:

```
jQuery(".see-more").click(function() {
       maxLength = 1000;
});
```

Depends of the scope of the first `maxLength` definition.

Comment: this does not work, is it because I need to run the first function again with this click? If so how do I do it?

Comment: yes, if you want to change the html code after changing the variable, you need to run the code changing the html after the variable change

Comment: I tried this but it did not work at the end of the function i included:
maxLength();

Comment: now I really don't understand what is the real problem...